# Convert date time to a formatted time string

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I don't know why it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
> t <- hms("14:11:49")
> t
[1] "14H 11M 49S"
t <- t + minutes(3)
> format(t, format="%H:%M:%S")
[1] "14H 14M 49S"
# Expected output: "14:14:49"
```

**Update:**

Currently I found this solution, but I hope there is a more elegant one:

```
t <- hms("14:11:49") # example period object
sprintf("%s:%s:%s", hour(t), minute(t), second(t))
#"14:11:49"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure why we need to convert to `hms` and back to initial string format. Maybe `parse_date_time` function is what you need:

```
library(lubridate)

myTime <- "14:11:49"
hms(myTime)
#"14H 11M 49S"

POSIXct_myTime <- parse_date_time(myTime,"hms")
format(POSIXct_myTime, format="%H:%M:%S")
#"14:11:49"
```

---

**EDIT:**
We can use `paste`:

```
tt <- hms("14:11:49")
tt
#[1] "14H 11M 49S"
tt <- tt + minutes(3)
tt
#[1] "14H 14M 49S"

paste(hour(tt), minute(tt), second(tt), sep = ":")
#[1] "14:14:49"
```

Benchmark output:

```
big <- rep(tt, 10000)
bench::mark(
  paste = paste(hour(big), minute(big), second(big), sep = ":"),
  sprintf = sprintf("%s:%s:%s", hour(big), minute(big), second(big)),
  shosaco = format(Sys.Date() + big, "%H:%M:%S"))
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression    min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#   <bch:expr> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 paste      27.7ms 29.8ms      30.9  312.69KB        0    16     0      517ms
# 2 sprintf    29.5ms 42.7ms      23.3  312.69KB        0    12     0      515ms
# 3 shosaco    28.3ms 29.2ms      33.1    2.06MB        0    17     0      514ms
# # ... with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>,
# #   gc <list>
```

Comment: This does seem like a better idea.

Comment: I consider (paranoically) the string format save some bytes for each entry when writing to the text file. Your solution however does not do what I am trying to achieve. This line is `chicken-egg` problem: `POSIXct_myTime <- parse_date_time(myTime,"hms")`. I don't have myTime in string format. I read millions of entries in `%H:%M:%S` format, filter them and want to write back out exactly same format as of the input.

Comment: "...the string format save some bytes for each entry when writing to the text file..." - not sure this is true... Also, "...I don't have myTime in string format..." - in your post you are passing a string to hms - `hms("14:11:49")`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I only put the line `hms("14:11:49")` to just to create an object out of a time string. My workflow is like this: read in millions of entries of time string; use lubridate to do some calculation; write back out to text file the result. Please check the beginning of my updated question

Comment: @biocyberman see update with paste solution and benchmark output.

Comment: I forgot about the `paste` function in this case. But I was hoping that there is a way to avoid calling `hour`, `minute` and `second`. My thought: The `lubridate` package is obviously very  good at reading in many input date time formats, but not very good at giving those outputs back out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `paste` solution prints "04" as "4". I added a simple workaround using the `format` function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `class(t)` is "Period" and the `format.Period()` function does not have a parameter for `format=`. The `t` object is not a standard `POSIXt` style object that you may be used to using with `format()`. Only the `format.POSIXct()` and `format.POSIXlt()` functions will behave like that.

So perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to define a helper function to turn the `Period` class into `POSIXct`. We can do that with:

```
as.POSIXct.Period <- function(x, start=today()) {
    X<-as.interval(x, start); 
    X@.Data+X@start
}
```

It's important to note that `POSIXct` is a date/time value, not just a time value. So by default we just assume it started at midnight today. But then we can use format in the way you wanted

```
format(as.POSIXct(t), format="%H:%M:%S")
# [1] "14:11:49"
```

I must admit I'm not an expert `lubridate` user so perhaps I've overlooked an obvious function, but it seems the options for formatting `lubridate` classes into "pretty" formats are very limited.

Comment: This solution works, but require an extra step to convert the time to date_time object. Anyways, thanks for mentioning the `format.POSIXct()` and `format.POSIXlt()` functions.

Comment: Well, your original question was just you didn't know why it doesn't work, it wasn't asking for a "solution" to anything. If that wasn't your actual question, then I would try to better word your questions in the future. I only did the conversion because you seem to really want to use the `format` function with the `"%H:%M:%S"` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution does not print leading zeros. The following solution seems to be more elegant:

```
> t <- hms("14:01:49") + minutes(3)
> sprintf("%s:%s:%s", hour(t), minute(t), second(t))
[1] "14:4:49" # looking weird
> format(Sys.Date() + t, "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "14:04:49" # looking better
```